# Could not do an indexed read to get the next row

Tags: php, informix

I have this connection class, where I connect with several databases.
I need to adapt so that the Informix database performs a read-only query. Ignoring whether the table is lock.

The message returned with the lock table is this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   -246 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Could not do an indexed read to get the next row. sqlerrm(retrieve row by rowid)

In this excerpt I set the parameter `set isolation to dirty read;` but it didn't work.

```
$conn = new PDO("informix:host={$host}; service={$port}; database={$name}; server={$server}; protocol=onsoctcp; set isolation to dirty read;EnableScrollableCursors=1", $user, $pass);
```

Below the whole class:

```
<?php

class connection {

    public static $conn;
    private static $last;

    public static function open($basename) {
        if (file_exists("config/{$basename}.ini")) {
            $db = parse_ini_file("config/{$basename}.ini");
        } else {
            throw new exception("Error connect '$basename'");
        }

        $user = isset($db['user']) ? $db['user'] : NULL;
        $pass = isset($db['pass']) ? $db['pass'] : NULL;
        $name = isset($db['name']) ? $db['name'] : NULL;
        $host = isset($db['host']) ? $db['host'] : NULL;
        $type = isset($db['type']) ? $db['type'] : NULL;
        $port = isset($db['port']) ? $db['port'] : NULL;


        switch ($type) {
            case 'pgsql':
                $port = $port ? $port : '5432';
                $conn = new PDO("pgsql:dbname={$name}; user={$user}; password={$pass};host=$host;port={$port};");
                break;
            case 'mysql':
                $port = $port ? $port : '3306';
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};port={$port};dbname={$name}", $user, $pass);
                break;
            case 'sqlite':
                $conn = new PDO("sqlite:{$name}");
                break;
            case 'ibase':
                $conn = new PDO("firebird:dbname={$name}", $user, $pass);
                break;
            case 'oci8':
                $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname={$name}", $user, $pass);
                break;
            case 'mssql':
                $conn = new PDO("mssql:host={$host},1433;dbname={$name}", $user, $pass);
                break;

            case 'informix':
                $port = $port ? $port : '1528';
                $server = 'ol_standard';
                $conn = new PDO("informix:host={$host}; service={$port}; database={$name}; server={$server}; protocol=onsoctcp; set isolation to dirty read;EnableScrollableCursors=1", $user, $pass);
                break;
        }

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        self::$conn[$basename] = $conn;
        self::$last = $basename;

    }

    public static function select($sql, $base = null) {

        if (!$base)
            $base = self::$last;

        return self::$conn[$base]->query($sql);

    }

    public static function exec($sql, $ret_id = false, $base = null) {

        if (!$base)
            $base = self::$last;

        $retorno = self::$conn[$base]->exec($sql);
        if ($ret_id)
            $retorno = self::$conn[$base]->lastInsertId();
        return $retorno;

    }

    public static function close($base = null) {

        if (!$base)
            $base = self::$last;

        self::$conn[$base] = null;

    }

}
```

Comment: You've not shown the SQL statement that you're executing when you get the exception.  That makes it hard to pontificate on why it might be running into the error.  Normally, the -246 error means that someone else (or the same user in a different database session) has parts of the table locked because of uncommitted updates, and the current session runs into one of those locks.  But without the SQL statement, and an outline schema of the table(s) involved, it is hard to say much more.

Comment: Not sure adding a "set isolation to ..." in the connection string will work.  Have tried doing it after you create the connection? Something like $conn->query("set isolation to dirty read")

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you